# Solutions to complex linear equations in given regions of the plane

Tags: complex-numbers, algorithms, computational-mathematics

I have (*many*) equations of the form $$T = z + S \omega,$$ where $T$ and $S$ are complex numbers such that $|T| < 1$ and $|S| = 1$.

I am looking for solutions where $0 < {\rm arg}(z) < \pi/2$; $-\pi/2 < {\rm arg}(z) < 0$; $|z| < 1$; and $|\omega| < 1$. (*i.e.* $z$ and $\omega$ lie in the first and fourth quarter unit discs).

If solutions do not exist in these regions, I would like to find $z$ and $\omega$ in these regions where the error is minimised.

My first thought was to approximate the quarter discs with simple polygons and calculate the intersection ([figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUFRy.png)), then find the average of the vertices. This turned out to be very slow.

Is there a 'fast' algorithm to find solutions in the required regions? (Here fast probably means using basic operations and/or a small number of iterations).